# tinyMCE textarea cannot set x and y coordinate

Tags: textarea, tinymce-4

Is there a way to position and size tinymce textareas using x and y coordinates?

I have multiple textareas and need to have dynamic text areas and position them according to x and y coordinates.

Any suggestion on how to acheive this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following lines of code worked for me:

var directParent = $('#'+getObjectItem.id + '_ifr').closest("div").attr("id");

var originalHTMLParents = $('#'+directParent).parent().attr("id");
var originalParent = originalHTMLParents.split('-')[0];
$('#'+originalParent).css({"left": tleft, "top": ttop}); //add X(left) and Y(top) values here